# SQL Server - SQL to see if an expression is a built-in function

Tags: sql-server

If have the situation where I want to know if some text is a built-in sql function such as CONVERT or DATEADD. Is there any simple way of doing this?

Rgds

Ben

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL management studio with intellisense turned on, `reserved words` will be highlighted.

There is also a list of reserved words on [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx)

Comment: Hi Chris, I would like to check during the processing of a stored procedure. So looking for some SQL to tell me if some text refers to a built-in function or not.

Comment: @BenWatson I'd suggest holding the reserved words in a separate table and joining that table to see if there is a match.

Comment: This is possible...... hoping for a solution that did not involve maintaining a table. If sql server has no simple way of exposing this, then that is possible.

Comment: @BenWatson I don't believe it's possible - the good thing is that the reserved word list doesn't change very often!